# using ellipsis with label that is not starting from the div's begining

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a label that is located inside a dynamically sized div.
the label starts from about the middle of the div
I am trying to add ellipsis to it but I just cant get it to start the ellipsis in the correct place

here is my code:

```
 <div id="container" style="text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow:hidden;width:50px">
 <label id="myLabel" style="left: 20px!important;position: absolute;">test1234567890</label></div>
```

what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Why you are using `position: absolute;`? http://jsfiddle.net/7ZK9s/

Comment: for the "left" attribute, otherwise it wouldn't effect the label

Comment: Can you explain me what you want as the end result? and for left, you can also use `position: relative;`

Comment: my end result will be as follows : http://jsfiddle.net/tqBsM/ but with an ellipsis within the label

Answer (score 0):

Ellipsis property won't affect absolutely positioned element's,  if you want to move label left AND keep ellipsis, you should set `padding-left:20px;` to div

Comment: OK thats the right direction, but it creates a new problem. my actual goal is to have a div that contains more then the label element, something like:  <div id="container" style="text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow:hidden;width:50px;background-color:red">
     <div style="width:5px; background-color:yellow" />
     <label id="myLabel" style="padding-left:15px;">test1234567890</label></div>